# how to add same background color for all pane in javafx?

Tags: javafx-8, javafx-css

I want to maintain single background color(black) for all panes, and for all views. i don't want write css for every view. i am using only vbox and hbox mostly. and very few table views. is there any easy way to write css once and apply to all. thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't write a css for every view, you give every element the same style class.

```
    Pane pane = new Pane();
    pane.getStyleClass().add("bg-black-style");
```

Somewhere you need to add the stylesheet to the scene

```
scene.getStylesheets().add("css-file.css");
```

And in the css file

```
.bg-black-style {
    -fx-background-color:  black;
}
```

This way every thing that should look the same has it's style all in one place.

Comment: I'd prefer this solution over the brute force `.pane { /* ... */}` variant.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use .pane in CSS class, and it will work for all the panes.

```
    .pane{
        -fx-background-color:  black;
    }
```

Same works with .button etc.

Comment: Just a heads up.  As of right now, this is not working. (Atleast for me)  However, it does work for other elements like buttons.

Comment: it didn't work for me either for split pane or anchorpanes, however, i was able to get what i wanted by using just an asterisk in place of .pane so it looks like this instead:  * { ... }

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the style sheet to the entire application like this:

```
package hacks;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.net.URL;

/**
 * Created by BDay on 7/10/17.<br>
 * <br>
 * CssStyle sets the style for the entire project
 */
public class CssStyle extends Application {
    private String yourCss = "YourResource.css";

    public CssStyle() {
        try {
            Application.setUserAgentStylesheet(getCss()); //null sets default style
        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            System.out.println(yourCss + " resource not found");
        }
    }

    private Button button = new Button("Button Text");
    private TextArea textArea = new TextArea("you text here");
    private ObservableList<String> listItems = FXCollections.observableArrayList("one", "two", "three");
    private ListView listView = new ListView<String>(listItems);
    private FlowPane root = new FlowPane(button, textArea, listView);
    private Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private String getCss() throws NullPointerException {
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        URL resource = classLoader.getResource(yourCss);
        String asString = resource.toExternalForm(); //throws null
        return asString;
    }
}
```